# Negative exponential curve in R using ssasymp - Predict values for theoritical days

Tags: r

I have the following table for 27 days. (column days_in_chamber). It corresponds to a negative exponential curve that I created with the following function:

> nls(perc ~ SSasymp(daysinchambers, Asym, R0, lrc), data = exp_perc_prvi)

I already fitted this a model that yielded a asym, lrc and r0 values.

Now, I want to predict values with those coefficients for 7 more days. Therefore, I should have 7 new values in the first column for days 28, 29 ... until 34.

Here's the data set:

```
dput(prvi_cut) structure(list(Prvi_Dro1_B3_R15_perc = c(100, NA, 93.6663935183579, 90.0585704623119, 86.7818450917892, 83.6078741753943, 80.3996517742901, 77.8764590673719, 75.3190148757444, 73.2867601163261, 71.1403337412101, 69.3478393747569, 67.6466823008618, 65.934108065397, 64.3585397687693, 62.7601371490021, 61.2302374986535, 59.8715952718514, 58.3645299446423, 56.9830533947007, 55.6472454910381, 54.4256092030731, 53.2496415613873, 52.14217688912, 51.0118778937132, 50.1099221297017, 48.6371082872019, 48.2375076322601), daysinchambers = 0:27), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163" )) .
```

Here's the model output:

```
dput(modelcut)
    structure(list(id = "Prvi_Dro1_B3_R14_perc", Asym = 24.8385975483755, 
        R0 = 100.000000546026, lrc = -2.90002359059106), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If someone could help me, it would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this via the `predict` function, passing in a data frame containing the desired values of `daysinchambers`

```r
mod <- nls(perc ~ SSasymp(daysinchambers, Asym, R0, lrc), data = exp_perc_prvi)

new_df <- data.frame(daysinchambers = 28:34)
new_df$perc <- predict(mod, newdata = new_df)

new_df
#>   daysinchambers     perc
#> 1             28 47.75121
#> 2             29 47.01360
#> 3             30 46.31677
#> 4             31 45.65847
#> 5             32 45.03658
#> 6             33 44.44906
#> 7             34 43.89404
```

To see what this looks like, we can use `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(exp_perc_prvi, aes(daysinchambers, perc)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = 'actual'), size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = new_df, aes(color = 'predicted'), size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'nls', se = FALSE, linetype = 2, linewidth = 0.5,
              formula = y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc), color = 'black',
              fullrange = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>